# Deploying to OpenBSD without a Ruby Manager (RBENV/RVM)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zsh, rbenv, capistrano3, openbsd

The package manager in OpenBSD has a good naming convention, so it's not necessary to include RVM or RBENV as a Ruby manager. I've read through the docs and it seems as though Capistrano requires RBENV or RVM to be installed.

Is it possible to use the system Ruby gems with Capistrano?

I'd like to keep it simple and use the OpenBSD package manager, however if a Ruby manager is required, then I'd use RBENV. OpenBSD uses the `zsh` shell, so even by installing RBENV, the RBENV script cannot execute because it's based on bash.

How can I make RBENV compatible with zsh/OpenBSD if?

Comment: The default shell in OpenBSD is ksh not zsh.  If you need bash do doas pkg_add bash

Answer (score 1):

Personally, it's a double-edged sword.

You don't need RVM or rbenv, in fact, capistrano requires [an extra gem for RVM](https://github.com/capistrano/rvm) [or this one for rbenv](https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv).

But at the same time when using ruby from your OS package manager you end up needing `sudo` for installing gems which is not ideal and might pose a securitiy risk. Check the [Authorisation docs](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/authentication-and-authorisation/#authorisation) for more info about it.

I'd use either RVM or rbenv in order to have a more *sudoless* secure environment.

About rbenv and zsh, it does work with zsh but it might need the bash package to be installed. For using rbenv you just need to have the init script running in your `.zshrc` to use it. I have personally used rbenv in the past with zsh.

Comment: Most of the gems don't require doas (that is like sudo in OpenBSD/adJ).

Answer (score 0):

Capistrano does not require rbenv or rvm.

The capistrano-rvm/rbenv gems exist only to allow a Capistrano deployment to work in such an environment. When not used, the deployment will use the default system Ruby, which seems to be what you want.

The only caveat is that you will probably need to install Bundler system-wide. You might find that in your package management system, or need to run `sudo gem install bundler`.

Once Bundler is installed, Capistrano executes Bundler with the `--deployment` and `--path` flags in order to install all the remaining Gems in a folder which is local to your deployment. This is in order to avoid the sudo problem mentioned by Pedro.